# How to edit/remove the Resources-links on Central Admin start page

Tags: central-administration

In SP2013, on prem:
On Central administration's start page you can add you own links to the right (under the title "Resources").

I have done so, but accidently linked to the wrong location. How do I remove links from this list? (in gui or powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Central Admin:

1. Click the gear icon and click `Site Contents`
2. Find the `Resources` list
3. From here you can delete the link like any list item

Comment: Wow! That must be some kind of record in fast an accurate response, Im not even allowed to set it as accepted for 8 more mins (but will do)! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help out